# Entity Framework Azure SQL connection string in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have the following `appsettings.json` file, with the connection string taken from my Azure SQL database dashboard:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": 
    {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=60;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

which seems not to work. Is there some more specific formatting it has to undergo?

Answer (score 1):

Without having the exact information on the error that you are getting and the place where you are trying to use the connection string, first thing I would check is, if the development mode is enabled and if it is looking for an "appsettings.Development.json" file.

If this is not what it is, please update the question with the error that you are getting with the exact line where you are getting the error.

Comment: That's the issue, I can't seem to find any error messages. And I know for sure there is data in the table etc.

Thanks for the dev-mode tip, will check it out!

Comment: You might find the error in the debug console output window of whichever code editor you are using VS or VSCode.